# Linux User Process Context to Access User virtual memory

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

Say I have the user context data stored in a kernel memory pointer. Say I also have a pointer to user-space char *. Then I create a kernel thread and kernel thread can have these two pointers. From the thread can I access the user space data using the pointer? I can access them in the system call but the question is can I access them from kernel thread? What about accessing them from Workqueue?

Say my userprocess calls a system call

```
//User Application
char* abc = "This is data.";
syscall(340, p);
```

in syscall handler

```
void sys_340(void* p) { 
    th = kthread_run("kth", kt_func, p);
    //might also store process context as I am in system call!! How?
}

void kt_func(void *p) { 
    while(1){ printk("Line: %s\n",p); sleep(1000); } 
}
```

I want kt_func to print "This is data" in every 1 seceond.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel threads can access any part of user space memory(given that they have the proper pointer to it). As you code suggests that as a part of system call you want to start a new kernel thread and let it print something every 1 second. I am assuming that after creating the kernel thread, you would return from the system call. The problem here is this: Once you have returned from the system call, the user process can also access the memory pointed by **p** and the kernel thread can also access it. How would you assure synchronization access of the pointer **p** ? ( Perhaps through another system call).

Although, I cannot see any use case of what you are doing ?

Comment: Lets forget the synchronization issue. The problem is that after the syscall returns to kernel, I am no longer getting the right value pointed by p. p is userspace virtual address and can be translated to physical address using the processor context. Kernel threads runs in different processor context. So just by using *p I can not access value. My question is how can I access the value provided that I can preserve the task_struct current pointer of the process along with pointer p.

Answer (score 0):

In your syscall handler, you could do something like

```
struct mm_struct *mm = get_task_mm(current);
```

to stash away the memory mapping of the process making the system call.  Then later in your kernel thread you can do something like

```
access_remote_vm(mm, p, my_kernel_buf, length, 0);
```

to do the equivalent of `copy_from_user()` on the original task's memory.

Comment: That is exactly my question. How to do access_remote_vm. Is there any particular implementation in kernel 2.6?

Comment: Not sure what you mean: yes, there is a function `access_remote_vm()` in kernel 2.6 that you can call.

Comment: Sorry, I searched the function access_remote_vm in LXR for 2.6.38 and could not find it. But I found access_remote_vm function in LXR for 2.6.39 now. Will try this.